# Read things out of database WHERE 'id'=

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to build an examine (Dutch = overhoor) program in Python. Here's my code:

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()

willekeurig = random.randint(0,9)

query = ('SELECT FRwoord, NLwoord FROM unite8app1 WHERE "id"=willekeurig')
cursor.execute(query)

for (NLwoord, FRwoord) in cursor:
    print("Wat is de vertaling van: " + FRwoord + "?")

vertaling = input()

if vertaling == NLwoord:
    print("Well done")
else:
    print("Helaas")

for (FRwoord, NLwoord) in cursor:
    print(FRwoord,NLwoord)
print(query)
cnx.close
```

I am trying to get a random question based upon the id of that question in my database. I tried some alternatives like:

```
WHERE 'id'=1
WHERE 'ID'=1 
etc
```

But it doesn't want to work if I run my program (after pressing enter) it says that NLwoord and FRwoord aren't defined, but when I remove that bit of code it works just fine. (if I have just 1 item in my database)

My question is how to grab a random id from my database? I have included some pictures of the database.

http://updo.nl/file/37e39c15.JPG
http://updo.nl/file/1de64d64.JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are not passing the value of willekeurig, but the text willekeurig. Try these two lines for your query & execute insted:

```
query = "SELECT FRwoord, NLwoord FROM unite8app1 WHERE id=%s"
cursor.execute(query, (willekeurig,))
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Beside the text I tried to use instead of an id, was it bad to put quotes around id?

Comment: If you have server option `ANSI_QUOTES` enabled, then you can use double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this without any quotes around id?

You should also be able to use:

```
SELECT FRwoord, NLwoord FROM unite8app1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I have already tried "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1", but I think it might be hard to prevent asking the question twice.